# Use TypeScript Enum with PropTypes to define React Component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the Component and I use TypeScript Interface to define its props:

```
interface Props {
    headerType: DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE, //DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE is enum
    headerContent: SVGClass
    isReverse: boolean;
};

const MyComp: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {};
```

Then I use PropTypes to validate its props in runtime:

```
DropDownMenu.propTypes = {
    headerType: PropTypes.oneOf(DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE), //error here
    headerContent: PropTypes.instanceOf(SVGClass),
    isReverse: PropTypes.bool
};
```

And I got this error:

**Argument of type 'typeof DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE[]'.**

**Type 'typeof DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 16 more.**

How can I use TypeScript `enum` with `PropTypes`? And how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
const DropdownMenuType = PropTypes.oneOf(
  Object.values(DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE) as DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE[]
);

DropDownMenu.propTypes = {
  headerType: DropdownMenuType,
  ...
};
```

Works for me whenever I need to validate against enums.

Answer (score 0):

If your enum has numeric values and you want to pass such values, try

```
headerType: PropTypes.oneOf(
  Object.values(DROPDOWN_MENU_TYPE).filter(x => typeof x === 'number')
)
```